# New Magento Instance vs Magento Multi store?

Tags: magento2, multi-website

What are some of the scenarios/ use cases in which an enterprise should go ahead with multiple Magento instances instead of using Magento multi-site feature.

I am still trying to wrap by head around Global, websites, stores and store views and I wanted assistance in helping me understand this with a real world example.

The company I work with is a retail group that has a pharmacy, fashion, fitness and healthcare business.

1. The 4 businesses have a common/ shared team that handles their Ecommerce
2. All 4 businesses have a different set of products with less than 5% of the products overlapping
3. All 4 businesses have their branding and brand guidelines
4. All 4 businesses have different warehouse/ stock sources
5. Some businesses are multi national (or aiming to become multi national) but serve different set of countries. Eg:
   a.  Pharmacy serves in 2 countries and 2 currencies
   b.  Healthcare serves in 1 country and 1 currency
   c.  Fitness services in 5 countries and 4 currencies

In this case, what is the easiest way forward?

1. Should there be 4 Magento instances, 1 for each business?
2. Should there be 1 Magento instances with 4 websites, 1 website for each business?

I would appreciate if you can help me understand the possibilities and pros and cons of each possibility.

Thank you very much and looking forward.